# transactionmanager using same datasource

Tags: java, hibernate, spring, datasource, sessionfactory

**(connected to db call abc)--->datasource1 --->** LocalSessionFactoryBean   --->transactionManager1

**(connected to db call abc)--->datasource1**----->AnnotationSessionFactoryBean -->transactionManager2

the reason i have 2 sessionfactory is because one is used by 3rd party osworkflow library and latter use by my application

since both are connection to **same "datasource1" (same database)**, i can use either one as service layer transactionmanager right ?

```
    <bean id="annotatedsessionFactory" class="org.springframework.orm.hibernate3.annotation.AnnotationSessionFactoryBean">


        <property name="packagesToScan" value="com.company.model" >
        </property>


 <property name="mappingResources">
            <list>
                <value>com/opensymphony/workflow/spi/hibernate3/HibernateCurrentStep.hbm.xml</value>
                <value>com/opensymphony/workflow/spi/hibernate3/HibernateHistoryStep.hbm.xml</value>
                 <value>com/opensymphony/workflow/spi/hibernate3/HibernateWorkflowEntry.hbm.xml</value>
                  <value>ahxu/workflow/hibernate3/PropertySetItemImpl.hbm.xml</value>
                   <value>com/opensymphony/user/provider/hibernate3/ahxu/impl/HibernateGroupImpl.hbm.xml</value>
                   <value>com/opensymphony/user/provider/hibernate3/ahxu/impl/HibernateUserImpl.hbm.xml</value>
            </list>
        </property>


        <property name="hibernateProperties">
            <props>

                <prop key="hibernate.dialect">org.hibernate.dialect.Oracle10gDialect</prop>
                <prop key="hibernate.show_sql">true</prop>
                <prop key="hibernate.format_sql">true</prop>
                <prop key="hibernate.use_sql_comments">true</prop>
                <prop key="hibernate.cglib.use_reflection_optimizer">true</prop>
          <!--      <prop key="hibernate.hbm2ddl.auto">update</prop>   -->
                <prop key="hibernate.c3p0.min_size">5</prop>
                <prop key="hibernate.c3p0.max_size">20</prop>
                <prop key="hibernate.c3p0.timeout">1800</prop>
                <prop key="hibernate.c3p0.max_statements">50</prop>
                <prop key="hibernate.cache.provider_class">
                      com.services.ExternalEhCacheProvider
                </prop>
                <prop key="hibernate.cache.use_second_level_cache">true</prop>
                <prop key="hibernate.cache.use_query_cache">true</prop>



            </props>
        </property>
        <property name="dataSource">
            <ref bean="dataSource" />
        </property>

    </bean>
```

I get error

```
org.springframework.beans.factory.BeanCreationException: Error creating bean wit
h name 'annotatedsessionFactory' defined in ServletContext resource [/WEB-INF/ap
plicationContext.xml]: Invocation of init method failed; nested exception is jav
a.lang.NullPointerException
        at org.springframework.beans.factory.support.AbstractAutowireCapableBean
Factory.initializeBean(AbstractAutowireCapableBeanFactory.java:1338)
        at org.springframework.beans.factory.support.AbstractAutowireCapableBean
Factory.doCreateBean(AbstractAutowireCapableBeanFactory.java:473)
        at org.springframework.beans.factory.support.AbstractAutowireCapableBean
Factory$1.run(AbstractAutowireCapableBeanFactory.java:409)
        at java.security.AccessController.doPrivileged(Native Method)
        at org.springframework.beans.factory.support.AbstractAutowireCapableBean
Factory.createBean(AbstractAutowireCapableBeanFactory.java:380)
```

Comment: I changed "jpa" to "hibernate" since you are not using JPA (EntityManagerFactory)

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Use one `SessionFactory`

`AnnotationSessionFactoryBean` extends `LocalSessionFactoryBean`, so it has all of its capabilities.

Comment: the reason is the 3rdparty  osworkflow using .hbm mapping,  while my app using annotation mapping. how to combined into one?

Comment: just use AnnotationSessionFactoryBean. It has the capabilities of LocalSessionFactoryBean